# Currency convert in category page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

I want show in category multiple curency price

i have a code tike this

```
$this->currency->convert($price, 'RUB', 'CNY'),
```

Where to put this in caregory controller for working?

Comment: What is your OC version? Do you want to show price in different currencies for each product?

Comment: Opencart 2.3.0.2

Comment: Your question is too vague. You need to describe exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem like this

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                $price_2 = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), 'CNY');
            } else {
                $price = false; 
                $price_2 = false;   
            }
```

Maybe someone have better way to make.